# Java mouse event listener returning 4 times instead of once per click?

Tags: java, events, mouseevent, mouse

Okay I've programmed a game for my A-level computing project, and I've started implementing an inventory system. However, my mouse input detection is throwing off the mouse clicked event 4 times instead of just the once and I don't understand why. It's causing issues as when i click on an inventory item, it is trying to remove 4 items from the slots list rather than just the one, which throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when there is less than 4 items occupying that slot.

Here is the mouse event class:

```
package com.ritcat14.GotYourSix.input;

import com.ritcat14.GotYourSix.events.EventListener;
import com.ritcat14.GotYourSix.events.types.MouseMovedEvent;
import com.ritcat14.GotYourSix.events.types.MousePressedEvent;
import com.ritcat14.GotYourSix.events.types.MouseReleasedEvent;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

private static int mouseX = -1, mouseY = -1, mouseB = -1;
public static boolean left = false, right = false;

public EventListener eventListener = null;

public Mouse(EventListener listener) {
  this.eventListener = listener;
}

public static int getX(){
    return mouseX;
}
public static int getY(){
    return mouseY;
}
public static int getButton(){
    return mouseB;
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseB = e.getButton();

  MousePressedEvent event = new MousePressedEvent(e.getButton(), e.getX(), e.getY());
  eventListener.onEvent(event);
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseB = MouseEvent.NOBUTTON;

  MouseReleasedEvent event = new MouseReleasedEvent(e.getButton(), e.getX(), e.getY());
  eventListener.onEvent(event);
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();

  MouseMovedEvent event = new MouseMovedEvent(e.getX(), e.getY(), true);
  eventListener.onEvent(event);
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();

  MouseMovedEvent event = new MouseMovedEvent(e.getX(), e.getY(), false);
  eventListener.onEvent(event);
}

}
```

And here is where and how i'm trying to use it, in the `Slot.java` class' update method:

```
public void update(){
  super.update();
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(getAbsolutePosition().x - 50, getAbsolutePosition().y - 50, 50, 50);
  Point p = new Point(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY());
  if (Mouse.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && rect.contains(p) && !selected && items.size() > 0) {
      selected = true;
      s = new Slot(new Vector2i(Mouse.getX() - 25, Mouse.getY() - 25));
      addComponent(s);
      s.add(items.get(items.size() - 1));
      items.remove(items.get(items.size() - 1));
  } else if (Mouse.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && rect.contains(p) && selected) {
      clicked ++;
      s.add(items.get(items.size() - 1));
      items.remove(items.get(items.size() - 1));
  } else if (Mouse.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3 && rect.contains(p) && selected) {
      items.add(s.getItems().get(s.getItems().size() - 1));
      s.getItems().remove(s.getItems().size() - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your onEvent code? And given the fact that you say your're wanting clicks - why then did you ignore mouseClicked and instead fire on pressed/released/moved?!

Comment: @Jan Those are for a different event system used by the player. The way i've used in the update method works (detects clicked events), it is just that it fires 4 times instead of just once